# What ways to remove objects the same id, when concat 2 arraylist of objects use rx in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 lists and they can have the same objects with the same id, and I want to leave only one.

How it make use operator filter?

```
val query1: Observable<ArrayList<Ops>> = Observable.fromArray(listResult)
val query2: Observable<ArrayList<Ops>> = Observable.fromArray(adapter.items)
Observable
    .concat(query1, query2)
    // .filter{} // how?
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        val list = it // expect only unique obj
        adapter.items = list
    }
```

Or exist another simple aproach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val query1: Observable<ArrayList<Ops>> = Observable.fromArray(listResult)
val query2: Observable<ArrayList<Ops>> = Observable.fromArray(adapter.items)
Observable
    .concat(query1, query2)
    .flatMapIterable { concatList -> concatList }
    .distinct { opsItem -> opsItem.id }
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        val list = it // expect only unique obj
        adapter.items = list
    }
```

Comment: can you explain: 'it' - this is ArrayList<Ops>, and we can't call "it.id"

Comment: it is the receiver, it means it's the item emitted by the observable.
In your case it will be "Ops" object.

 Observable.just(listOf("",""))
            .distinct { opsItem -> opsItem.id }

Comment: probably need to add also .toList() .toObservable() - to convert back to list of out objects

Comment: Yes, i forgot it at first